# how to get next batch number corresponding to product code with php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Please help me to find next batch number corresponding to product code with using PHP and MySQL. My table is like below given image:

[Table Screenshot](http://www.mediafire.com/view/4s67ahmtkwnu71i/mmmmmm.jpg)

If I want to enter new batch of product RM-SO-070G then the PHP form must get new batch number accordingly.

Comment: What do you mean? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL should look something like this ...

```
SELECT `some_tbl`.`batch_no` FROM `some_tbl` WHERE `some_tbl`.`product_code` = ? ORDER BY `some_tbl`.`batch_no` DESC LIMIT 1
```

And then once you get these results you will need to remove the `bt` from the front of the `batch_no`

```
$next_batch_no = intval(substr($result_row['batch_no'], 2))++;
```

Comment: once I echo the first query it it displays "array"... why is that ?

Comment: @ManishaSilva MySQL is returning an array try `print_r`, and you should read a tutorial to get you started on selecting data from a database though PHP using PDO (http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly/) is a good one

Answer (score 0):

Create an additional table that will pose as a sequencer - the table will have just one column holding the next batch value. Each time you add a new product to your initial table, you take the batch number from the sequencer table and update the sequencer with the next batch number you want for the next product you add.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$product = "RM-SO-070G";
$previous = "bt001";
$query = "SELECT batch_no FROM table WHERE product_code = '".$product."' 
              AND batch_no = (SELECT MIN(batch_no) FROM table 
                  WHERE batch_no > '".$previous."');";
$result = mysql_query($query);
...
```